My products are not showing on homescreen of ecommerce website for MERN PROJECT
i have made a ecommerce website useing nodejs as backend and reactjs as frontend and mongodb database but i could nt see a single data on homescreen and site keeps showing double products and categoriesemphasized text
**[Homescreen for products][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Q8xA2.jpg
import { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async'
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox'
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox'
// import data from '../data';
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true }
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, products: action.payload, loading: false }
    case 'FETCH_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
function HomeScreen() {
  const [{ loading, error, products }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    products: [],
    loading: true,
    error: '',
  })

  // const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' })
      try {
        const result = await axios.get('/api/products')
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data })
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAIL', payload: err.message })
      }
      // setProducts(result.data);
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>SmartBazar</title>
      </Helmet>
      <h1>Featured Products</h1>
      <div className="products">
        {loading ? (
          <LoadingBox />
        ) : error ? (
          <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
        ) : (
          <Row>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <Col key={product.slug} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} className="mb-3">
                <Product product={product}></Product>
              </Col>
            ))}
          </Row>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default HomeScreen**

